# Pitch vs Presentation

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

In sales terms I've met **pitch** for a lot of time as a sort of presentation. But what is this little difference between the **presentation** and **pitch** in term of *sales* or other public *speech* in a conference for example.

Answer (score 1):

A pitch is a specific kind of presentation, typically:

> - The pitch presentation is a 20-minute (or so) slide presentation, usually done live but with either PowerPoint or Keynote slides in the background, that tells investors about a new business.

[Sales pitch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pitch) in the modern commercial advertising sense is from 1943, American English, perhaps from the baseball sense.

Answer (score 1):

In a presentation you are just literally giving facts. Usually this is to arm someone with information about a decision they will ultimately make, or information they need to learn. In a pitch however, you are calling them to take the action you want them to take. It is, by nature a persuasive argument.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that supports this answer?

Comment: @Scott It seems to me you asked for a very strange thing because it's obvious that this answer is based on personal experience rather than any references.